# XMLHttpRequest in Cordova for android

Tags: android, cordova, request

I'm actually stuck with a problem. Building a app in Cordova, for Android. I need to download a PDF from a variable path in the server. With a documentation from Cordova said "Transition off of cordova-plugin-file-transfer", located [here](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html) , I tried this:

```
 var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Make sure you add the domain name to the Content-Security-Policy <meta> element.
        oReq.open("GET", endereco, true);
        // Define how you want the XHR data to come back
        oReq.responseType = "blob";
        oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
          var blob = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
          if (blob) {
              console.log("WORKS??");
          } else console.error('we didnt get an XHR response!');
        };
        oReq.send(null);
```

where "endereco" is a variable where I store the pdf path. So, I'm testing and testing, but maybe someone got some pointers in how to implement this. Right now it just log "WORKS??", so I actually connected successfully. But what now?

1 - so, I made a request, but the file was saved? Couldn't find nothing in my mobile. How can I save said blob in a folder, with the same name and extension from the server?

So, if someone can at least send me to some proper examples or documentation, it would help a lot. Right now I'm reading all on MDN Web Docs, but I'm fairly noob with this type of code :(

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

so, this is how it worked for me! Using the info from the official documentation at cordova, formerly named "cordova-plugin-file" ([link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)), and the amazing info from this page with examples "CORDOVA FILE PLUGIN EXAMPLES"  ([link](https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/)) it worked. It could use some cleanup and some error callbacks, but right now I can run this, and download and save an pdf to my android. Hope it helps someone! B-)

```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

function onDeviceReady() { 
    var fileURL;

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", endereco, true);
req.responseType = "blob";

req.onload = function (event) {
  var blob = req.response;
  console.log(blob.size);
  console.log(blob.type);
  console.log("WORKS!");
  console.log(fileURL);          

  // cordova.file.etc is where you will save the file. In this case, inside the app folder, in the main storage in Android
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
    // the 'temp.pdf' is the name you want for your file.
    directoryEntry.getFile('temp.pdf', { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
          // great success!
          console.log('Write of file completed.');
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
          // Meh - fail
          console.log('Write failed');
        };

        fileWriter.write(blob);
      } );
    } );
  });
};

req.send();}
```

Comment: Oh my!!!  Does this still work on the latest Cordova 11?  Still work with `cordova-android@11`???  If so, please post your full code with call backs.  I am transitioning off of `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` as I just finally migrated to Cordova11 and now my downloader functions are no longer working.  And the Cordova BLOG `https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html` does NOT work.  I am hoping yours does work as I am jumping through many hoops trying to come with an alternative solution.

Comment: In your code, you have a `console.log(fileUrl)` - that isn't defined here, but I assume you are just logging the full http/url path for testing purposes?  You are using `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory` - where is this?  I tested and it looks like it worked, but I can't find the file anywhere.

Comment: YES!!!  I got this working...but with one issue.  And I am writing successfully to `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`.  On Android, haven't tested iOS yet.  The one issue: the file IS being written to the directory, but console is printing out: "Write of file completed` AND `Write Failed'.   During error checking its giving a `FileError: 2` - yet it is succeeding.